# Inheritance in Java in interface and classes

Tags: java, inheritance, interface

I don't understand why in the code below the output of "j.m(b)" is "m_AA and m_BA" instead of "m_BB". Thank you.
(Only For SO: I don't know what I have to write , I don't know what I have to write ,  I don't know what I have to write ,  I don't know what I have to write,  I don't know what I have to write.)

```
interface I {
 public void m(A a);
 public static void stampa() {
  System.out.println("stampa");
 }
 class IImpl {
  public static void m(B b) {
   System.out.println("m_IB");
  }
 }
}
class A extends I.IImpl implements I {
 public void m(A a) {
  System.out.println("m_AA");
 }
}
class B extends A {
 public void m(A a) {
  super.m(a);
  System.out.println("m_BA");
 }
 public static void m(B b) {
  System.out.println("m_BB");
 }
}
public class Exercise {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  B b = new B();
  I j = new B();
  j.m(b);
  System.out.println();
 }
}
```

Comment: because `I` (the type of `j`) only has a method `m(A a)`.

Comment: Thank you! @f1sh